# Transform neural network error with loadcaffe?

Tags: torch

Wanna try the project https://github.com/chuanli11/CNNMRF. After cloning and installing loadcaffe by luarocks. Then run the comand:

```
qlua cnnmrf.lua -content_name master_entrance_portrait
```

Got this error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘data/result/’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘data/result/trans/’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘data/result/trans/MRF/’: File exists
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘data/result/trans/MRF/’: File exists
[libprotobuf WARNING google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc:505] Reading dangerously large protocol message.  If the message turns out to be larger than 1073741824 bytes, parsing will be halted for security reasons.  To increase the limit (or to disable these warnings), see CodedInputStream::SetTotalBytesLimit() in google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h.
[libprotobuf WARNING google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc:78] The total number of bytes read was 574671192
Successfully loaded data/models/VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers.caffemodel
qlua: ...torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/SpatialConvolution.lua:19: nOutputPlane should be divisible by nGroups
stack traceback:
    [C]: at 0x7fec4cde29d0
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    ...torch/install/share/lua/5.1/cudnn/SpatialConvolution.lua:19: in function '__init'
    ...yne/Downloads/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:91: in function <...yne/Downloads/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:87>
    [C]: in function 'SpatialConvolution'
    data/models/VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers_deploy.prototxt.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...oads/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/loadcaffe/loadcaffe.lua:24: in function 'load'
    ./transfer_CNNMRF_wrapper.lua:372: in function 'main'
    cnnmrf.lua:92: in main chunk
```

Guess caused by some underlying error in converting caffe model to torch model through loadcaffe. The net to be converted was VGG19 from the files VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers.cafflemodel and VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers_deploy.prototxt. I have checked these files by checksum, they were OK. But the converted one, that is, VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers_deploy.prototxt.lua was something like:

```
require 'cudnn'
local model = {}
table.insert(model, {'conv1_1', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1118555060, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47878672, 4, 64)})
table.insert(model, {'relu1_1', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv1_2', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 1041742427, 4, 1, 0, 0, -76411872, 4, 64)})
table.insert(model, {'relu1_2', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'pool1', cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0):ceil()})
table.insert(model, {'conv2_1', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1172344618, 4, 1, 0, 0, -76404000, 4, 128)})
table.insert(model, {'relu2_1', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv2_2', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1134797354, 4, 1, 0, 0, -76401184, 4, 128)})
table.insert(model, {'relu2_2', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'pool2', cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0):ceil()})
table.insert(model, {'conv3_1', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 32609, 4, 1, 0, 0, -76397968, 4, 256)})
table.insert(model, {'relu3_1', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv3_2', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 976600020, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47647424, 4, 256)})
table.insert(model, {'relu3_2', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv3_3', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1193143920, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47644208, 4, 256)})
table.insert(model, {'relu3_3', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv3_4', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 965660278, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47640880, 4, 256)})
table.insert(model, {'relu3_4', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'pool3', cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0):ceil()})
table.insert(model, {'conv4_1', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 994497290, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47635600, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu4_1', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv4_2', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 994239873, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47631248, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu4_2', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv4_3', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1162151849, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47626896, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu4_3', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv4_4', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1161155618, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47622544, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu4_4', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'pool4', cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0):ceil()})
table.insert(model, {'conv5_1', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 990007184, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47617264, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu5_1', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv5_2', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1165327502, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47612912, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu5_2', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv5_3', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1173363995, 4, 1, 0, 0, -338687408, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu5_3', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'conv5_4', cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, 980886043, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47608144, 4, 512)})
table.insert(model, {'relu5_4', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'pool5', cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0):ceil()})
table.insert(model, {'torch_view', nn.View(-1):setNumInputDims(3)})
table.insert(model, {'fc6', nn.Linear(0, 0)})
table.insert(model, {'relu6', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'drop6', nn.Dropout(0.500000)})
table.insert(model, {'fc7', nn.Linear(0, 0)})
table.insert(model, {'relu7', cudnn.ReLU(true)})
table.insert(model, {'drop7', nn.Dropout(0.500000)})
table.insert(model, {'fc8', nn.Linear(0, 0)})
table.insert(model, {'prob', cudnn.SoftMax()})
return model
```

Found it was in loadcaffe.lua:

```
C.convertProtoToLua(handle, lua_name, backend)
```

then in ffi.lua:

```
ffi.cdef[[
...
void convertProtoToLua(void** handle, const char* lua_name, const char* cuda_package);
...
]]
```

Does this mean the loadcaffe installed in luarocks was damaged before install? What could be the cause? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: For instance, the third line: cudnn.SpatialConvolution(0, -1118555060, 4, 1, 0, 0, -47878672, 4, 64) cause the error. What are -1118555060, -47878672 for?

Comment: You see I got nothing from anyone! Those WT or NG damaged the file, don't you think so?

Comment: what kind of error message to you get? you keep speaking about an error but you don't explain it

Comment: fonfonx, I have edited the message added the root cause. Please help me out.

Comment: thanks it is easier to try to help you. What is your OS? How did you download the prototxt and model files?

Comment: My oprerating system is Ubuntu 14.04. I download files from linkages from here: https://gist.github.com/ksimonyan/3785162f95cd2d5fee77

Comment: I have checked the md5sum of these files. All were OK.

Comment: OK, I dunno if it changes anything but I exectued this script: https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style/blob/master/models/download_models.sh (as suggested in the readme) to download the models and the VGG_ILSVRC_19_layers_deploy.prototxt.lua was perfectly fine...

Comment: Have you tried out it? At first time, I have downloaded them.

Comment: I just ran the script and then ran the `cnmrf.lua` script and the prototxt.lua file was correctly created with the good values

Comment: I did the same thing but I got the error I showed you. What could be the cause?

Comment: frankly I dunno. You could try removing loadcaffe and reinstalling it with gcc5. Not sure if that changes anything: `CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 luarocks install loadcaffe`

Comment: fonfonx, when did you install loadcaffe? Can you reinstall loadcaffe and run cnmrf.lua again? I guess the loadcaffe module on the server is damaged.

Comment: I installed it 2 days ago, with gcc5 :)

Comment: @fonfonx Hi, I installed gcc-5.1 and g++-5.1 then use the command: `CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5 luarocks install loadcaffe`. But this time I got the error: `libloadcaffe.so   undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameB5cxx11Ev`. Then I followed andrefaraujo in this thread [here](https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe/issues/45) and git cloned and installed the most recent protobuf but not to find `_ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameB5cxx11Ev` in my libprotobuf.so. How to solve it? Which version of protobuf should I install that contain this symbol?

Comment: just to be sure, have you run `sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler`?

Comment: Already installed. When I run the command: `sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler`. It showed: `... libprotobuf-dev is already the newest version. protobuf-compiler is already the newest version. ...` Could you please run the command: `grep _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameB5cxx11Ev ....../libprotobuf.so` to see if this symbol is there in this so?